# How point-contact transistor work?

Tags: electric-circuits, resource-recommendations, history, electronics, electrical-engineering

In December 1947 Bardeen, Brattain and Shockey introduced a device which is considered to be the first transistor. This transistor was point-contact device. So, it used metal-semiconductor junctions.
According to book *History of semiconductor engineering* by Bo Lojek (2010), a principle of such transistor has never been fully understood:

> ...but as matter of fact, a good solid physical theory of point-contact transistor does not exist and even today we do not know, for example, why point-contact transistors occasionally exhibit negative resistance behavior.

As to produce point-contact transistor (or diode) is rather art (because each piece of semiconductor can have different impurities, damaged crystal grid etc. and it also depends where a metal contact is made), it seems obvious that each transistor could show different behavior (mentioned negative resistance, unstable gain etc.). These were reasons why Shockley worked out theory of P-N junctions and based on it introduced junction transistor which behavior is predictable.

I understand that point-contact transistor is now very obsolete device, however, I wonder if there is (or was) any research trying to understand point-contact transistors functions. Any information, paper etc. will be highly appreciated.

**Cross-posted on [SE.Electrical Engineering](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/540384/)**

Comment: Would [electronics.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: I would have to agree with Qmechanic. This is definitely a physics question, but not many on this site have the expertise to give you a good answer.

Comment: If you are wondering about "negative resistance", that is negative _differential_ resistance, also seen in tunneling diodes.

Comment: Frankly I don’t believe that comment. It seems the author just thinks it should act like a bipolar transistor and since it doesn’t it must be unknown how it works. Decades ago we actually got taught how a point contact junction works.

Comment: @JonCuster: Yes, that is a reason why I am suprised as Shottky junction is well understood.

Comment: @Pieter: Thanks for pointing that out. It seems that there has to be some change in cariers mobility or something similar.

Comment: @KFGauss: Thanks. I will try to post there as well but I am interested mainly in physical mechanisms.